# Formatting JSON object and adding new keys to the structure

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new to JSON and would like some inputs. I have a JSON object of address that looks like below. There are mulitple address in the same key separated by ||.

Original JSON is: {"Address":"123 dead drive,camp hill,PA|| 456 N Street,Harrisburg, PA"};

I am trying to reformat this JSON to have 2 different address with comma separated as below.

```
{"Address":
       "Formatted Address" : 
               "Street Address":"123 dead drive"
               "City": "camp hill"
               "State": "PA" ,
       "Formatted Address" : 
               "Street Address":"456 N Street"
               "City": "Harrisburg"
               "State": "PA"
}
```

I am trying something like this

```js
$(function() {
   var resultJSON = '{"Address":"123 dead drive,camp hill,PA || 456 N Street,Harrisburg, PA"}';
var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);

var splitresult = result.Address.split("||");   
  address = [];  

  $(splitresult).each(function(index) {
      address.push({'Formatted': splitresult[index]});   
    });

  var json0bj =  JSON.stringify(address);
    console.log(json0bj);   
});
```

Comment: You would have to use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Commented code to show what had been done.
Made some small changes to your code:

```js
$(function() {
  var resultJSON = '{"Address":"123 dead drive,camp hill,PA || 456 N Street,Harrisburg, PA"}';
  var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);

  var splitresult = result.Address.split(" || ");
  address = [];

  $(splitresult).each(function(index, element) {
    // $.each passes the element as the second argument. We'll use that.
    var adrArray = element.split(',');
    // We split the string on commas to get the address fragments and place them  into a new object:
    var formattedAddress = {
      "Street Address": adrArray[0],
      "City": adrArray[1],
      "State": adrArray[2]
    };
    // Then push it onto the array:
    address.push({
      'Formatted Adress': formattedAddress
    });
  });

  //To make the result look like the one you want we put the array into a new structure:
  var addressObject = {
    "Address": address
  };
  var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(addressObject);
  document.write("<code>"+jsonObj+"</code>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to provide an explanation as to what changes were made and why. Else little is learned by any reader.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It worked but when I added my other object to the list, it gave me syntax error. I just got the actual json object with array. actual object is this.$(function() {
  var resultJSON = '{
        "EmployeeID": "491772",       
        "addresses":["123 dead drive,camp hill,PA" || "456 N Street,Harrisburg, PA"]}';
  var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);

}); I missed before square brackets in address. Appericate your help.